# How do I output all field values from a Category on the current entry?

Tags: category

I'm building my first site with Craft, so this is a bit newbie question.

I've build a category with a some fields.
How can I output all fields form the selected category on the current entry?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a [Categories field](https://craftcms.com/docs/categories-fields) on your entry called `myCategoryField`, you can check if it has any Categories selected by going:

```
{% if entry.myCategoryField | length %}
    There are categories selected!
{% endif %}
```

If you want to loop through all of the selected categories for that field, you can do:

```
{% if entry.myCategoryField | length %}
    <ul>
        {% for category in entry.myCategoryField %}
            <li>{{ category.title }}</li>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

For more info you can read more in the [templating section](https://craftcms.com/docs/categories-fields#templating) of the Categories field's documentation.