# How can I get an entry's child category, and not the parent category?

Tags: categories, children

I have a category page that lists all of the entries related to that category. And then I want to display the selected child category for the entry... in brief like so:

**Entry Title 1**
*Entry 1's Child-Category*

**Entry Title 2**
*Entry 2's Child-Category*

**Entry Title 3**
*Entry 3's Child-Category*

My category field handle is `chooseLocation`

Here is what I have in my template:
[(snippet taken from here)](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/16328/how-do-i-output-all-field-values-from-a-category-on-the-current-entry)

```
{% for entry in entries %}
    {% if entry.chooseLocation | length %}
    {% for category in entry.chooseLocation %}
         <a href="/location/{{ category.slug }}">{{ category }}</a>
            {% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The problem is, this get's the parent category (which is the category page we're on) but not the *child* category. I need to show just the child category and not the parent.

I've looked through the docs but I can't find anything on how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Categories field (`entry.chooseLocation`) is an **Element Criteria Model**. It's exactly the same as if you'd done something like this...

```
craft.categories.group('myGroup')
```

The Element Criteria Model (ECM) is an important concept in Craft, because it's the driver for *most* content handling. Once you've got a bearing on what the ECM is, you can use it fairly consistently.

For example, just like `craft.entries`, you can apply `.find`, `.first`, and [other methods](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/16070/45) to retrieve a specific subset of elements. And depending on the element type, you can chain other filtering methods in between...

```
craft.categories.group('myGroup').limit(3).find()
```

Returning to your question, `entry.chooseLocation` will be an ECM for Categories. So it's just a matter of filtering it appropriately.

```
{% for category in entry.chooseLocation.level(2).find() %}
```

Here is the [full list of filtering options](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.categories) you can use on a Categories ECM.

Comment: Hmmm I may also have something else buggy going on... When I update my code to include `.level(2).find()` like you show above, I get nothing, when I change it to `.level(1).find()` it works and shows the parent. I double checked my entries I'm testing against, and I've selected the child category and saved, but when I look at the `chooseLocation` field, it shows the parent category as the chosen option. Screenshots - select the child category: https://goo.gl/RDjCzj and what shows after selecting the child category: https://goo.gl/HRJssb. I'm not sure if that is normal behavior or not though.

Comment: Ah, I think I see what's happening... When you created the field, did you limit the maximum to `1`? That actually prevents child categories from being selected (since the parent will _always_ be selected).

Comment: Yes, that was it! I had the limit set to 1 :/  I removed that, reselected the child category for each entry, and now `{% for category in entry.chooseLocation.level(2).find() %}` works perfectly :)

Comment: Great! It's a quirky limitation, and ends up being a "gotcha" for a lot of people. :)